# Menu names are missing

Tags: interface

[image]When I go to sculpting mode the names next to the various items are missing. They show on each item as I hover over it but they should all be showing. I pulled the menu out so they should all show but no luck. Is there a setting to make them all show?

Comment: Although I don't know what happened I was able to correct the situation by restoring factory defaults and then re downloading the template file. Somehow something got changed or corrupted in the first template file I downloaded.

Comment: Which menu items do you talk about? Please [edit] your post to include details and screenshots of your situation.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I tried to post a jpeg image of the situation in my original post ( well under the 2M limit) and kept getting errors. Maybe because I am new? Only after I removed the pic was I able to post. I am on blender 4.0 and when in sculpture mode there is a menu on the left side showing all the tools (brush, clay, etc.). When we pull that menu out to the right the menu/toolbar expands to show the names that each icon represents. Something happened to where my menu names no longer appear.

Comment: @Don The labels aren't missing, they are (almost) white on white background. So not a bug but an issue on the colors of your theme.

Comment: Although you say that you've sorted the problem, it looks as if it may have been showing white text on a white background for some odd reason so as @Lutzi says, a theme colour problem.

Comment: White on white makes sense but I have no idea how it got that way???

Comment: This isn't the default theme, so how did you set it white like this?

Comment: I have no idea???